# Get custom field value from not-current page

Tags: customization

What is the best way of getting a custom field value from a page which is not the one currently displayed? I know the title of the page i want to get custom field value from, but not the pageID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($id, $key, $single);
```

With $single set to true if you don't want WP to return an array for unique meta keys.

Comment: I don´t have the post id available. I only know the title of the page

Comment: Is there a way of submitting a page/ post title and get the ID in return?

Comment: Not short of querying the db directly. (There's a function to get the post by url, though.) You can see the ID by editing the post - it appears in the url.

Comment: There **is** [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) function, not sure if it works for posts (from brief look at code it takes `$post_type` argument so might).

Comment: Oh woops. I stand corrected. :-)